# How to place two views on opposite side of LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout-gravity

How can I place the ImageButton on the right side of the screen ?

[image: How it is right now]

I think it has to do with "layout_gravity" property, but I can't manage to figure out how to do it.
Here is the XML file that creates each line :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_generated_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/list_generated_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use rtl attributes. check this documentation LayoutDirection | Android Developers https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line in your Text View

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Then all will be done as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_generated_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/list_generated_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"/>

</LinearLayout>
```